# Reach Router Cannot read property 'apply' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, reach-router

I have code structured like so

```
App.js

<Router>
 <Dashboard path="/appName/dashboard" />
 <Workflow path="/appName">
  <Details path="item/details" />
  <Cases path="cases/open" />
  <Cases path="cases/closed" />
 </Workflow>
</Router>
```

In my Dashboard component I have  component, like so:

```
<Link to={`/appName/item/details?id=${id}`} ><button>{id}</button></Link>
```

And my Workflow.js is like so:

```
Workflow = ({ children }) => {
 return (
  <div>
    <main>{children}</main>
    <aside><AsideMenu /></aside>
  </div>
 )
}
```

However when I click on the link to go from Dashboard to Details component, I navigate to it and then get the error **Cannot read property 'apply' of null**

I switched the Link to /appName/cases/open?id=${id} and still got the same error.

When I directly load these pages, I do not get an issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: First error]
[image: Second error]

Comment: Where are you receiving the `id` from? Are you getting it from props?

Comment: Yes, the id I get it from props

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the Router in the wrong way. A valid React Router reprensentation can be like following:

Router Component

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/appName/dashboard"><Dashboard /></Route>
     <Route path="/appName">
       <Workflow />
     </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Workflow component:

```
 <Switch>
   <Route path="/item/details"><Details /></Route>
   <Route path="/cases/open"><OpenCases /></Route>
   <Route path="/cases/closed><ClosedCases /></Route>
 </Switch>
```

Comment: Your code snippet about is for React-Router, I am using Reach Router. The issue ended up being a problem unique to both Reach and React Router libs https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7727

When you try to use fancy links, the lib gets confused and thinks it has to make an backend call instead of just routing on browser. So I switched Link in my Dashboard to just an anchor tag. And the issue got fixed.